# Cohomology of the restricted cotangent bundle on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb P^n$ of degree $n$. Assume that $X$ spans a $\mathbb P^k$. Then are the following true :

$(i)$ $H^0(\Omega _{\mathbb P^n|_X}(1))= H^0(\Omega _{\mathbb P^k|_X}(1) \oplus \mathcal O_X^{\oplus (n-k)})$

$(ii)$ If $X$ spans $\mathbb P^n$ (i.e. $k=n$), then is $X$ a rational normal curve in $\mathbb P^n$? (is this an alternative definition of rational normal curve? in that case can anyone suggest me a reference discussing this?)

From the Euler sequence we have $\Omega _{\mathbb P^n|_X}(1)$ is the kernel of the surjective map $\mathcal O_X^{\oplus n+1} \to \mathcal O_X(1)$ and similarly $\Omega _{\mathbb P^k|_X}(1)$ is the kernel of the surjective map $\mathcal O_X^{\oplus k+1} \to \mathcal O_X(1)$. But I'm unable to see how this $H^0$ relation follows from there?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in (i)? You're asking about $H^0(A)\cong H^0(A\oplus B)$ where  $B$ has nonzero global sections. (ii) Is pretty standard, for instance [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179041/characterization-of-rational-normal-curve).

Comment: @KReiser, actually the point of $(i)$ is that starting with $X$ just a curve in $ \mathbb P^n$, I want to show that $X$ must be rational normal curve. If $ X$ spans $P^k$ and $(i)$ is true the using the additional information that the left hand side of $(i)$ is zero ( which I didn't mention in the question), I can deduce $k$ must be $n$ and hence $X$ is rational normal by $(ii)$. But I don't know what extra hypothesis guarantee the $H^0$ relation in $(i)$.

Comment: Well, that's not true unless $k=n$. Take a plane curve of degree $d>2$ sitting linearly in $\Bbb P^d$ via the embedding $\Bbb P^2\to\Bbb P^d$ by $[x_0:x_1:x_2]\mapsto [x_0:x_1:x_2:0:\cdots:0]$. Again, see the linked question for how to understand what's going on here - your current strategy will not work.

Comment: @KReiser, if I know that in addition $ h^1( \Omega_{\mathbb P ^ n}|_X(1))=0$, then can we say that $(i)$ is true?